# Redux, I can modify the state - it is not read only, outside of an action dispatch?

Tags: redux, react-redux

Perhaps someone can shine some light here for me.

I have been doing redux, and just was reading about and I read "State is read only". Ok, I figured that was the case - but let me try.

So, in my component I wrap it in a connect and what have you and now I have access to the state... so, I did this, in the render method.

this.props.state.MYSTORE = {}

Well, that actually killed my store. I get the concept of pure functions, but this idea that the 'state is read only' is not entirely true. I figured it would kill just this instance of the store (passed into my component), but the actual store is kaboomed!! I'm a little confused with "state is read only" - clearly, it is not.

What is actually read only? I get that you set state via action creators, but that doesn't forbide bad practice. Just like in a regular component you use "setState", BUT you could just make an assignment on the state tree...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much of Redux's behavior is expectations and convention over an absolute enforcement.  If you're using plain objects for your Redux state, technically you *can* mutate it directly if you want (but it's almost always a *very* bad idea!).

Beyond that, Redux is primarily a way to organize all the "write" logic for your application into a single structured approach, rather than having random writes scattered throughout your codebase.

If you do want additional assistance to make sure you don't ever actually mutate your state accidentally, there's several tools you can use.  The [DevTools#Linting](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/devtools.md#linting) page of my [Redux addons catalog](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links) lists some plugins that will warn you if you accidentally mutated the state, although those obviously should only be used in development.  You can also use a specific [immutable data](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/immutable-data.md) library to either "freeze" your plain objects or give you a specialized set of data structures that wrap up your state contents.